# Colorful and named after famous people

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**I'm looking for a 4-word title.**

---

Known for being old, slow and harmless but not these guys - "special" and the complete opposite!

[image]

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> **Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles**!

To find this, first identify the four people in the images. These are (clockwise from top left):

> The author, **[Gioconda Belli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gioconda_Belli)** (found using reverse image search);
>  The actor, [**David Hasselhoff**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hasselhoff);
>  The poet, [**Magdalene Thoresen**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdalene_Thoresen) (found using reverse image search);
>  The singer, [**Madonna**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madonna).

Pleasingly, all of these personalities are representatives of *the arts*. This is appropriate because if we interpret "C(name)" to suggest...

> ...'Creator of (name)', then we are able to find four *artists* who created works sharing their titles with the names of these four people, and whose own names begin with the letter in red:
>
>  *[Gioconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa)*, by **Leonardo** da Vinci;
>  *[David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(Michelangelo))*, by **Michelangelo**;
>  *[Penitent Magdalene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penitent_Magdalene_(Donatello))* by **Donatello**;
>  The *[Sistine Madonna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistine_Madonna)* by **Raphael**.

And, of course...

> ...the names of these artists are also the names of the [*Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles) from comic books, TV and film!

The title and flavourtext contain many pointers towards this solution:

> 1. The Turtles are '*colorful*', in that each one wears a different-coloured bandana;
>  2. The Turtles are indeed '*named after famous people*';
>  3. Turtles in general are renowned for '*being old, slow and harmless*'...
>  4. ...but these Turtles are quite the opposite: teenaged ninjas, and *special* (mutants) too!

Comment: Great job! Everything looks good 